# Return <td> formatted as <a> link [ajax]

Tags: html, mysql, ajax

I want to return a mysql query result field to html as a clickable formatted link.

```
//I want to format clmLink as a clickable link
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
    $display_string .= "<tr>";
    $display_string .= "<td class='td1'>$row[clmDate]</td>";        
    $display_string .= "<td class='td2'>$row[clmnames]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td class='td3'>$row[clmComment]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td class='td4'>$row[clmLink]</td>";               
    $display_string .= "</tr>";
```

```html
<head>                  
    <style> 
         .td4 {
             padding-right: 20px;
             padding-top: 10px;
             background-color: #E6E6FA;
             width: 100px;          
        }           
    </style>         
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `<a>` tag like this :

```
$display_string .= '<td class="td4"><a href="'.$row[clmLink].'">'.$row[clmLink].'</a></td>'
```

If you don't want to use only a `<td>`, you will have to use some Javascript to make your `<td>` clickable and add some css like this :

```
.td4{
    cursor : pointer;
    color : blue;
}
.td4:hover{
    color : light-grey;
}
```

Comment: I tried this;  $display_string .= "<td class='td4'><a href="'.$row[clmLink].'">'.$row[clmLink].'</a></td>"; and it returned the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in bla bla bla

Comment: You should use `'` instead of `"` as I did.

Comment: It returned an error MatthieuLemoine so I changed it to see if it would block the error.

Comment: Maybe i made a syntax error but i can't try it now, you just have to add a `<a>` tag to your fourth `<td>` to do what you want to do. But you have to be careful with your quotes, in html you have to use " and not '. In PHP you can use both but if you use " and you write html in it you will have to use \".

Comment: @MatthieuLemoine in _html_ you can also use both `'` and `"` for quoting the attributes: [W3C - HTML5 - 4.4. Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes). `"` is somehow more common, but `'` is also valid for quoting.

Comment: It works perfectly. I didn't add a semi-colon at the end of the line of code. Thank you very much. Much appreciated MatthieuLemoine